# Github Actions Error on "Run google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master" . How to resolve this?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am using Github actions to deploy my application to Google cloud and it gave me following error -

```
Run google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
Warning: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud is pinned at "master". We strongly advise against pinning to "@master" as it may be unstable. Please update your GitHub Action YAML from:

    uses: 'google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master'

to:

    uses: 'google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0'

Alternatively, you can pin to any git tag or git SHA in the repository.
Error: On 2022-04-05, the default branch will be renamed from "master" to "main". Your action is currently pinned to "@master". Even though GitHub creates redirects for renamed branches, testing found that this rename breaks existing GitHub Actions workflows that are pinned to the old branch name.
```

Comment: Change to  `uses: 'google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0`

Comment: It had been working fine with this warning till yesterday, can you please explain why this build failed as github said they ll be changing on 4th April 2022.
Just trying to understand :) @eyllanesc

Comment: Probably little by little things are breaking within the GA, therefore the previous warning. Is it so difficult to make the change?

Comment: not difficult, I want to understand if i change will there be any ill-effects

Comment: That's why the warning yells at you: Don't use master because I can fail at any time, and now I'm failing. The "2022-04-05" is another abrupt change that will be different from the current one. If you want more details, create an issue in the repo so that the developers (if they have time) can give you more details.

Comment: I don't understand what kind of answers you want, the warning is very clear: Don't do what you're doing, I'm warning you.

Comment: thanks, got it, makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That 3rd party action is moving away from the convention of using a branch named `master`.

Instead of:

```
uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
```

Change the reference in your YAML to:

```
uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0
```

Comment: it was working and now its throwing error 
```
deploy
Process completed with exit code 1.
```